# ASP.NET Master page DefaultButton override

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, defaultbutton

I have a master page with a form element and the defaultbutton attribute set to a server-side ImageButton.  On one of my pages I want to "override" the masterpage defaultbutton attribute by setting the Forms DefaultButton in the Page_Load event.

i.e 
On mater page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSearch">....</from>
```

On the page Page_Load event that "override" the master page attribute:

```
this.Form.DefaultButton = this.ibRecalc.ID;
```

It errors with :

> The DefaultButton of 'form1' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl

I am using image buttons which implements IButtonControl

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong or a different way to approach the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What type is ibRecalc? Does it implement the specified interface?

Comment: @Tahbaza: ibRecalc is a ASP.NET ImageButton control i.e it does implement IButtonControl

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use UniqueId.  Since you can have multiple server controls with the same server id, ie, in a GridView, the framework needs to the unique id to match up to.

```
this.Form.DefaultButton = this.ibRecalc.UniqueID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the "DefaultButton" property of a Panel...

Place your button or whole page or div in asp:Panel

// start panel

asp:Panel ID="pnlOpsCallSummay" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch"

............

//Controls of your requirement

..........

asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"

close the pannel

No need of Overriding the master page button

Comment: This is interesting, you will be able to have default buttons for multiple panels within one page then. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the panel inside the login's template:-

```
<asp:login id="Login2" runat="server" loginbuttontype="Image">
<layouttemplate>
   <asp:`enter code here`panel id="Panel1"   runat="\
     server"defaultbutton="LoginImageButton">
   </asp:Panel>
 </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Then it will work without code.
   You can set loginbuttontype="Image" or Link or button according to your  requirement.