# Can't span form over multiple divs

Tags: html

Whenever I use a `<form>` that's separated by the closing `</form>` via a `</div>`, the browser (chrome & firefox at least) closes the `<form>` tag. Below is the sample code

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form method="post" action="/api/users/">
    <textarea name="description">
    </textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevins8/BBfXb/)

Comment: Stick the opening/closing form tags outside the modal divs and wrap them both in a `modal-container` style thing.

Comment: You can put your `<input type="submit" />` outside your `<form>` by using the HTML5 `form` atribute. More at [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it the way you show; it's not valid HTML.

If you want to span the form across multiple `<div>`'s, you need to put the form tag outside them:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/users/">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <textarea name="description">
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: fair enough. I just wasn't expecting the browser to "autofix" it. Is there any way to turn of this "feature" out of curiosity?