# Form is spanned into 2 seperate divs => not validating properly

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, jquery-validate

**My form looks like this:**

[image]

My reduced in-lament code looks like this:

```
<div class="row no-pad">
    <form class="form-control-static" action="lib/leadGen.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left-hand-input">

            <label for="firstName">FIRST NAME:</label><br>
            <input required name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right-hand-input">
        <label for="lastName">LAST NAME:</label><br>
        <input required name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text"><br>
    </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

I am using [JQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) 
and after adding the library I just scripted this right before the body closes:

```
<script>
    $('.form-control-static').validate();
</script>
```

**The Issue:** it doesn't validate any `input` on the `.right-hand-input` div. 
Please feel free to submit any other libraries that overcome this issue.

> **EDITED:**  moved form outside of breaking divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Don't you make something like this?

```
<form class="form-control-static" action="lib/leadGen.php" method="post">

<div class="row no-pad">
    <div class="col-xs-6 left-hand-input">
            <label for="firstName">FIRST NAME:</label><br>
            <input required name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right-hand-input">
        <label for="lastName">LAST NAME:</label><br>
        <input required name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text"><br>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

and add some CSS to form tag to correctly reflect inside DIVs width

Answer (score 1):

> Please take note that i've already checked that a form separated by
>   divs is perfectly fine; noted in stackoverflow and other forums.

This is incorrect. Your HTML is invalid. What is happening is your  tag is getting closed for you and therefor everything in `right-hand-input` is not a part of `form-control-static`

See: [Can't span form over multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176098/cant-span-form-over-multiple-divs)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

Instead of just:

```
$('.form-control-static').validate();
```

Try writing:

```
window.onload=function(){
  $('.form-control-static').validate(); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sthlmsrille/d2hseLxe/

Comment: No, the library is in the head and loads before document loads.