# AngularJS: Call the ng-submit event outside the form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, form-submit

I'm a fish in AngularJS and I have this scenario.

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

In normal ways AngularJS provides the ng-submit directive to work as an attribute in the form but I need to call it outside.

So, someone has experienced the same problem? If yes, what you did?

Comment: I try to stay as a human when working in Angular, it can be far more advantageous

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please, surround your code with a ng-controller, and use ng-click on buttons out of scope of <form>.

I make a sample on jsfiddle for you... try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/xKkvj/2/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">Enter text and hit enter:
            <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
        </form>
        <button ng-click="submit()">Submit 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

with js:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.text = 'hello';
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.text) {
            $scope.list.push($scope.text);
            $scope.text = '';
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What if I need to pass the form for validation purposes?: `<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit(myform)">`

Comment: @benoror, I would to use an object to store input values (ex: $scope.data = {}), and use this on input (ng-model="data.text") and then, I would to pass this object on submit function: submit(data)

Comment: actually it's not necessary to put <button> out of <form>, attr type="button" just can be used in order for <button> not to submit the form

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo : can you elaborate more by example ?

Comment: @MayurBaldha I can help you. Please create a small chunk at plunker (or jsfiddle, etc) with your problem and post here the link.

Comment: @MayurBaldha There are a small error at your code. the ng-submit only run on forms, on buttons you need to use ng-click: button  ng-click="submit(form1)"... take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/joaozitopolo/xKkvj/446/

Comment: Form validation won't be triggered using this technique which kind of defeats the point of using a form in the first place...

Comment: @LeviFuller good question... I made the answer to help the asker. Personally I always use the form validation.

Answer (score 53):

Use HTML5's `form` attribute, here's a sample:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.submitted = false;
  
  $scope.confirm = function() {
    $scope.submitted = true;
  };
}]);
```

```css
form {
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
  <form id="myform" ng-submit="confirm()">
    <label for="myinput">My Input</label>
    <input type="text" id="myinput" name="myinput">
  </form>
  <br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="myform">
  
  <p ng-show="submitted">
    The form was submitted
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution does not appear to be supported by Internet Explorer http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute

Comment: Simplest fix. At first I didn't notice the form= value needs to match the id of the form, not the name of the form (in case it helps someone else). It can also be written as, `<button type="submit" form="myform">Save</button>`

Comment: By far the cleanest solution

Comment: This might be a clean solution, but this totally breaks internet explorer support @CorySchires is 100% right on this. I advise everyone who requires IE support to ignore this solution.

Comment: It is best to use native solutions like this one. If IE does not support this feature, you should decide not to support legacy browsers like these.

Answer (score 9):

This is by far the cleanest solution I found, all credits go to @Offereins https://stackoverflow.com/a/23456905/3819736

```
<form ng-submit="vm.submit()">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" />
</form>
<label for="submit-form">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</label>
```

This method doesn't require any additional controller JS or other jQuery tweaks.

Comment: @TVH7 That link shows only the `form=` attribute, as answered in stackoverflow.com/a/28432268/3150057, which definitely doesn't work in IE/Edge. This answer, however, is about the `for=` attribute, which is very common in html =)

Answer (score 5):

**Angular 2**

For anyone looking to achieve the same with Angular 2, ngForm exposes an event emitter you can use.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input autofocus type="text" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Name is required
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myForm.ngSubmit.emit()">Add</button>
```

You can also perform the same emit from inside your component ts/js file

Comment: This resolved my issue with submitting forms in IE 11 using angular 5. It looks like the above link is dead and is now here: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Answer (score 2):

All great answers, but the uber-solution, with all your options laid out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VWH1gVXjP2W9T9esnVZP?p=preview

```
  <form ng-submit="submit()" name="jForm" id="jForm" onsubmit="event.returnValue = false; return false;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="try to hit the enter key in here" />
    <div class="btn btn-default" id="tap">
      Tap me
    </div>

    <div ui-submit="" class="btn btn-primary">Submit form</div>
  </form>
  <ui-submitform class="btn btn-primary" formsubmitfunction="submit()">Submit form 2</ui-submitform>
  <button onclick="$('#jForm').submit()">jquery Submit</button>
```

and extending @m-k's and combing ideas from @joaozito-polo:

```
app.directive('uiSubmitform', function()
{
    // need this to make sure that you can submit your form by simply pressing the enter key in one of the input fields
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs)
     {
        element.onTrigger(function()
        {
          //scope.$apply(attrs.formsubmitfunction); 
            scope.$eval(attrs.formsubmitfunction);
        });
     }
 };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test code. The controller who has the login method is already called!

```
<form ng-submit="login()" id="form-test" name="formTest">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="userpass">
    <br>

    <!-- works -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit inside" id="test">
</form>

<!-- change the path from /#/login to /?username=aaa&userpass=aaa#/login and reloads the page-->
<button type="submit" onclick="$('#form-test').submit();">submit outside (jquery)</button> 

<!-- doesn't work -->
<button type="submit" ng-click="formTest.submit()">submit outside (ng-click)</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer Look at http://jsfiddle.net/84bodm5p/

---

Easiest way for me create special directive for external submission.

Important only use right event .triggerHandler('submit') on form element

```
$scope.$on('makeSubmit', function(event, data){
              if(data.formName === $attr.name) {
                $timeout(function() {
                  $el.triggerHandler('submit'); //<<< This is Important

                  //equivalent with native event
                  //$el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')) 
                }, 0, false);   
              }
            })
```

Look at my answer here [How to trigger form submit programmatically in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690230/how-to-trigger-form-submit-programmatically-in-angularjs/38038527#38038527)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking a handle of submitted state of form: 
In function ng-click just add vm.formName.$setSubmitted();

```
ng-click="vm.formName.$setSubmitted(); vm.submit()"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that works for me:

http://jsbin.com/ODaFaGU/3/edit

Check out the PART 2 and PART 3.

There are two solutions inside.

One for the regular form submit buttons - it allows you to tap the buttons without a delay, but also ensures that pressing the "enter" key in any of the form fields will trigger a submit.

Secondly there is an additional eventHandler that combines the click, tap and keydown[enter] events into a single one - this ensures that you can hit your controls as well with the keyboard, as with a click on desktop, and a tap on mobile(without hitting the click event twice) devices.

If you have any problems with this, give me a comment, I'll fix it.

Comment: Hi, it seems confusion for me because i am new to angular so i am sharing my fiddle like which can't be working in IE browser

http://jsfiddle.net/premraj10/LADWU/2/

main issue is after edit the row unable click the save event on IE browsers.


please have a look it and let me know your solution.

Answer (score -3):

In Angular you don't submit forms (well, at least in the angular way). You just need a function that will do what you want to do when you complete the form.

Just call that function in your `<button>` and you're ready to go.

Example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBYwYxx2Ik4h3j12ADre?p=preview)

Comment: This example isn't helpful if you're looking to take advantage of angular validation.  Angular validation is listening specifically for the submit event to run.