# IE browser issue with html5 attribute

Tags: html

I am getting a issue with button `type="submit"` or input `type="submit"` in **html5**, not working button action when checking in IE browsers please any suggestions.

My button action is outside from the Form tag

```html
<form>
     my code comes here
</form>
```

My button should be outside as per my requirement

```html
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your button is outside of **form** tag it won't submit that form.
To do this you have to use **jquery** button **click event** to submit that form

For Ex:-

```html
<form id="frm"></form><button type="submit" id="test"></button>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $("#test").click(function(){
          $("#frm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the question tagged with [jquery]?

Comment: The question not taged with jquery but I just suggest to use jquery to doing that thing

Comment: using Angular framework this is our code

<form id="rowform{{lrd.id}}" editable-form name="rowform" shown="lrd.isNew" onbeforesave="saveTable($data)"  ng-show="rowform.$visible" >
</form>

<button type="submit"  form="rowform{{selectedLrd.id}}" class="btn input-small btn-save" >Save</button>

can you give any solution on this

Comment: I hope this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581269/angularjs-call-the-ng-submit-event-outside-the-form
http://jsfiddle.net/xKkvj/2/

I have search for this and I found that you have to write your own JS code for submit the form.