# How to trigger form submit programmatically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

From Angular's documentation it follows that [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action) is a preferred way of submitting a form. All pending operations are immediately finished and `$submitted` flag is set as well. Whereas listening to `ngClick` event does not have the same effect.

Now I need to submit a form with hotkeys having all the goodies of `ngSubmit` approach. Hence I need some way to trigger standard submit workflow.

I tried `submit()` on DOM form and it worked, but angular's form object attached to scope contains no references to DOM form, thus I need to access it through jqLite:

```
var frm = angular.element('#frmId');
frm.submit();
```

I didn't like this solution for accessing DOM in controller code so I created a directive:

```
function wuSubmit() {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var scope = element.scope();
            if (attributes.name && scope[attributes.name]) {
                scope[attributes.name].$submit = function() {
                    element[0].submit();
                };
            }
        }
    };
}
```

which extends form object with `$submit` method.

Both variants do not work for yet unknown reason. `form.submit()` tries to send data, default action is not prevented.


**Update 1**
It turns out that Angular listens to click events of elements having `type="input"`.
Eventually I decided to trigger click event for that element:

```
wuSubmit.$inject = ['$timeout'];
function wuSubmit($timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var submitElement = element.find('[type="submit"]').first();

            if (attributes.name && scope[attributes.name]) {

                scope[attributes.name].$submit = submit;
            }

            function submit() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    submitElement.trigger('click');
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Is there any out of the box solution for this functionality?

Comment: How are you binding normal form submission in your form in HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use event .triggerHandler('submit') on form element.

```
myApp.directive("extSubmit", ['$timeout',function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr) {
            $scope.$on('makeSubmit', function(event, data){
              if(data.formName === $attr.name) {
                $timeout(function() {
                  $el.triggerHandler('submit'); //<<< This is Important

                  //equivalent with native event
                  //$el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')) 
                }, 0, false);   
              }
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/84bodm5p/

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive("form", function(){
     return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, form) {
            form.doSubmit = function() {
                form.$setSubmitted();
                return scope.$eval(attrs.ngSubmit);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="$ctrl.submit()" novalidate>
```

Then call in controller

```
$scope.myForm.doSubmit();
```

Comment: This is a novel solution, monkey-patch the ngFormController to add a `doSubmit` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your directive code a bit like:

```
function wuSubmit() {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var scope = element.scope();
            if (attributes.name && scope[attributes.name]) {
                scope[attributes.name].$submit = function() {
                    // Parse the handler of submit & execute that.
                    var fn = $parse(attr.ngSubmit);
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn($scope, {$event: e});
                    });
                };
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here you don't have to add `wu-submit` everywhere. `ng-submit` will work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: nope.. the problem is not in calling the same handler. The problem is in making angular to perform all operations like it does when real submit happens.

Comment: Do you mean performing validations & all by saying "Performing all operations"?