# Trigger ng-submit from directive

Tags: angularjs

This type of similar question has been asked and I followed all the suggestions still I am not able to trigger submit from directive. I have multiple form elements for multi step form validation and I have one click button to validate all forms. Here is the html.

```
<form name="employeePersonalForm" ext-submit
      ng-submit="emp.submittedForm(employeePersonalForm)" novalidate>
   <div layout="row">
       <div class="default-form-item pr-3" ng-class="{'md-input-invalid': employeePersonalForm.$submitted && employeePersonalForm.firstName.$invalid}" flex>
           <label class="default-label required">First Name {{employeePersonalForm.firstName.$invalid}} - {{employeePersonalForm.$submitted}}</label>
            <div class="default-input-wrapper">
                <input ng-model="emp.firstName" class="default-input" name="firstName" type="text" required>
                <p class="default-input-error">This field is required</p>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="default-form-item pl-3" flex>
           <label class="default-label required">Last Name</label>
           <div class="default-input-wrapper">
               <input ng-model="emp.lastName" class="default-input" type="text" required>
                <p class="default-input-error">This field is required</p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This type of multiple form exists in page. And there is one external button as follows.

```
<button class="default-btn default-btn--green" type="button" ng-click="nextStep($event)">Next</button>
```

On clicking of Next button, I am broadcasting event to submit the form. Here is the controller part.

```
emp.submittedForm = function(form) {
    if($scope.step==1) {
        alert(form.employeePersonalForm.$valid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid!!!');
    }
}
$scope.nextStep = function() {
    if($scope.step == 1) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('makeSubmit', {formName: 'employeePersonalForm'})
    }
};
```

I am catching this event in directive ext-submit as follows

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('extSubmit', ['$timeout', externalSubmit]);
/* @ngInject */
function externalSubmit($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            scope.$on('makeSubmit', function(event, data){
              if(data.formName === attr.name) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    el.triggerHandler('submit');
                }, 0, false);   
              }
            })
        }
    };
  }
})();
```

But it is not triggering ng-submit. I have followed this suggestion [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690230/how-to-trigger-form-submit-programmatically-in-angularjs/38038527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to simply execute the function in the `ng-submit` attribute:

```
app.directive('extSubmit', ['$timeout', externalSubmit]);
/* @ngInject */
function externalSubmit($timeout) {
    return {
        require: "form",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, form) {
            scope.$on('makeSubmit', function(event, data){
              if(data.formName === attrs.name) {
                //SET submitted state
                form.$setSubmitted();
                //EVALUATE ng-submit
                scope.$eval(attr.ngSubmit);
                //$timeout(function() {
                //    elem.triggerHandler('submit');
                //}, 0, false);   
              }
            })
        }
    };
  }
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $scope/$rootScope API Reference - $eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)
- [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference - $setSubmitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setSubmitted)

Comment: Thanks.It works great. But when we can execute ng-submit with eval why it is required to do form.setSubmitted? Shouldn't for should be automatically submitted after executing ng-submit?

Comment: Also I need to pass the employee form into my controller to check if the form is valid or not and based on that I go to next form.

Comment: Why doesn't the controller call `emp.submittedForm()` directly? It seems convoluted to broadcast a rootScope event to a directive to execute an AngularJS expression on an attribute.