# Submitting form from ngFormController

Tags: angularjs, forms

I've made my own form directive `<if-form form="vm.form" submit="vm.sendForm()"><if-fields></if-fields></if-form>`
In that directive I have regular form `<form name="vm.form">....</form>` 
In `vm.form` I have ngFormController (with $invalid, $dirty, $error and so on).

I want to submit form from outside `<if-form>`.
How can I submit form using `vm.form`? I want it to pass all validation. Is it possible?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581269/angularjs-call-the-ng-submit-event-outside-the-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-click to call your submit function from anywhere:

```
ng-click="vm.sendForm()"
```

or you can associate the separate submit button using form=""

```
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="vmForm">
```

Comment: Using vm.SendForm() won't trigger form validation. And input type=submit is also off the table because I want to use button outside if-form directive

Comment: If you use the first option you can check $scope.vm.form.$valid in your sendForm() function. 

If you are using the second option, the form="" part associates the submit input to the form, even if it is not inside the form.

Comment: That if I can check weather is $valid I know - but I cannot trigger validation as a whole. But I'm surprised on secon - I'll try it - EDIT: It's not working

Comment: Here is a very simple plunker showing a submit button outside the form submitting the form: http://plnkr.co/edit/imp2GtmAt22ybAWmDJ6y?p=preview

Comment: make sure the form="myForm" of the submit matches the id="myForm" of your form

Comment: Oh `id` - I know that I can submit form using it's id - didn't want that but guess don't have choice