# angular ionic - form submit with button that is not located within the form tags

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic-framework, submit

I’m using a library called floating-tabs.js which is being used to create floating navigational buttons: here’s an example of what the layout looks like

```
<floating-tabs>
     //this is my button
     <floating-tabs-item icon="ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" click="goNext(data)"></floating-tabs-item>
</floating-tabs>

<ion-content>
    <form name=“formName” ng-submit="goNext(data)">
        ***form stuff
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

How can I submit/validate the form without having my   button  inside the form tags

Thanks guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Call the ng-submit event outside the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581269/angularjs-call-the-ng-submit-event-outside-the-form)

Answer (score 0):

here i am using simple change password form.

```
<form name="changepasswordform"  novalidate>                                   
  <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" class="reset-inputs"  name="newpassword" ng-keyup="compare()"  ng-model="changePassword.newpassword" maxlength="10"  required/> 
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted && changepasswordform.newpassword.$error.required">Required</span>
 </form>
 <button type="button" class="reset-submit" ng-click="changepassword(changepasswordform.$valid,changePassword)">Change Password</button>
```

it consist button out side the form

and please use the script in your controller

```
$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.changepassword = function(formValidStatus, formdata) {
if (!formValidStatus) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
} else {
    $scope.submitted = false;
}
}
```

in the script i am checking form is valid or not if form is not valid i am showing error messages by using submitted variable from script.

This works for me