# Form Button Submit IE Issue

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer

I have a form that is submitted by a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" form="billing-form" value="xyz" name="abc">
```

That submits a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="billing-form" action="something.php">

//bunch of fields here

</form>
```

The button submits the form fine in most browsers except IE.

Any ideas how to make this work in IE?!  The button unfortunately has to be outside of the form itself which is why I'm using the billing-form name to reference.

Thanks,

NCoder

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if using simple script is not a problem then you can simply use an input button and submit the from using js

```
<input type="button" form="billing-form" value="xyz" name="abc" onclick="submitForm();">

function submitForm()
{
document.getElementById('billing-form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to work with the submit button outside the form without using javascript. See [This question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)