# Html browser compatibility submit type input

Tags: html, forms, cross-browser

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="select" id="selectForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" form="selectForm" />CheckBox
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" form="selectForm" />
</body>
</html>
```

witch in Chrome and FF does a page refresh then Submit is clicked, but in IE 11 does not.In IE 11 works only if the Submit button is inside the form.

Can you help me understand why ? Or is there a way make it work with the Submit button outside of the form ?

Comment: Why do u need it outside the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag

Comment: @YuriyGalanter : because I use a table to position the elements in the page, a part of the form is on top in a table row, and the Submit button is much lower in another table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to submit form universally by an outside button - just define a normal button and in it's `onclick` event handler do a `form.submit` e.g.

```
<form name="select" id="selectForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" form="selectForm" />CheckBox
</form>

<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('selectForm').submit();" />
```