# Submit a form via a button that is not inside of form

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to submit a form by clicking a button that is not inside of the form?

I have tried to set an id to the form and set the `target` attribute, but it seems not to work:

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text">
</form>

<input type="submit" target="myForm" value="submit">
```

I know it's possible via JavaScript (`form.submit()`), but is there any HTML native way to submit the form by pressing a button without of the form?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y97RT/1/)

Comment: If it's a layout issue, you can always stick the button in the form and use absolute positioning to visually move it elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Comment: @esqew Thanks! [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12567605/1420197) seems to be the answer for me. I expected this to be a duplicate... :-)

Comment: You can use a button to do it http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html http://jsfiddle.net/Y97RT/2/

Comment: an html5 solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/12567605/2985029

Comment: i like this html5 solution about what the point of submit button out of form tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax to send parameters and do the post form action in ajax page and then reset the form with status message below the form.

For ajax call

```
 var message = $('#message').val();
  //alert(true);
  if(message != '') 
  {
    var data ="message="+message;
    $.ajax({      
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: data,
      datatype:'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
        $('#form_status').html(response);
        $('#form_status').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            setTimeout("$('#form_status').fadeOut('slow');", 2000);
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

If you are looking for only html5 solution try this below one

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="something.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myform" />
```

Comment: Cannot understand why people use jQuery for submitting forms... I just wanted to use HTML only if possible.

Comment: then you have to put the submit button inside form end tag

Comment: There is no point answering this question as it will be closed for duplicate