# How can I submit multiple forms that come from a for loop in a click of one button in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

HTMLs that come from Database are being written to the screen by a for loop. Some of these HTMLs need to be submitted. What is wrong with the code?

```
<body>
    <%  int i;
        if (books != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
    %> 
    <hr>  

    <form class ="container" action="jspCheckBox.jsp" method="get" id="<%=i%>">

        <%
            if (books.get(i).getId() == null) {
                out.print("Axtardiginiz melumat tapilmadi");

            } else {
                out.print(books.get(i).getId());
            }
        %>

        <input type="checkbox" name ="id" value="<%=i%>"> Seç<br>
        <input  type="submit" style="display:none">

    </form> 
        <input  type="submit" form="<%=i%>" value = "Submit">

    <%
         }

      }

    %>

    <hr>
```

Comment: I think you should use javascript which should submit the form automatically as per condition that which one is to be submitted and which one should not.....

Comment: I tried with javascript, but it didn't work correctly. It was taking only the last form's id. [like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Comment: You want to submit them automatically ?? or by yourself ???

Comment: It should be done by users. They should be able to send any forms being created in a for loop by selecting checkboxes

Comment: are you ok with threading concepts because the solution i have thought involves threading concept

Comment: Can you explain the need for multiple forms?

Comment: I guess. Could you give an example?

Comment: @anpsmn I need forms in order to get HTMLs from a database by a for loop. You see, I  get each of them by a different form.

Comment: You can't send multiple forms with a normal HTTP call, AJAX is a must need. Or you will need a unique compound form.

Comment: @Jean This code works correctly in a small data 
 ` <%for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {%>
        <form class="container"action="jspCheckBox.jsp" method="get">
            <input type="checkbox" name ="id"value="<%=i%>"> Seç<br>
            <%}%> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             
        </form>` 
and send request **jspCheckBox.jsp?id=0&id=1&id=2** which selected id.
But more than 2 when the form is not working properly. How do I change that to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fix it.

```
 <form class ="container" id ="form" action="jspCheckBox.jsp" method="get">
        <%
            for (i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {

                if (books.get(i).getId() == null) {
                    out.print("Axtardiginiz melumat tapilmadi");
                } else {
                    out.print(books.get(i).getId());
                }
        %>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%=i%>" name ="id" > Seç   

        <%
            }
        %>
        <input  type="submit" value = "Selected " >
    </form>
```