# MVC Razor Using Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form like so in my View, but how do I make a select in my form, because i cant find any `SelectFor`.

And this form is in a modal dialog, the body. And so it the button, but I have the "Cancel" and "ok" buttons in the modal footer. So how can I remove the submit button from this form, and place it in the footer of the modal?

Thank you

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LeggTilUtdannelse", "Utdannelse", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Studiested, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Studiested, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Studiested)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Beskrivelse, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Beskrivelse, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fra, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fra, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Til, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Til, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Legg til" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to turn your modal into a form, i.e., instead of this: `<div class="modal fade">` do this: <`form class="modal fade" action="/Utdannelse/LeggTilUtdannelse" method="POST">`.