# How do I use ng-include to include a form and handle it in two different parts of an app?

Tags: angularjs, dry

Say I have an address form with a few fields (street, city, state, etc). The first time the user enters an address, he does it through a wizard. So I created a form (`formAddress`) that's handled by `WizardAddressController.createAddress()` that goes something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
self.createAddress = function ( form ) {
    self.user.all('addresses')
        .post( self.new_address )
        .then( function (address) {
            $state.go('next_step');
        });
};
```

So far so good. Now I have to use the same form and the same handling code on a different part of the app (a modal window in the user dashboard) to let the user add additional addresses and edit existing ones.

I want to use `ng-include` to include the form (which works good) and I want to use the same `createAddress()` function, but I can't use `ng-controller` for that matter since I need the code to resolve differently (instead of going to the next step, it should close the modal and show a success notice).

Of course, I want to behave as DRY (Don't Repeat Youself) as possible here.

Comment: Why don't you use a directive?

Comment: @Puigcerber, that looks like a suitable solution. But, how do I return the control to the corresponding controller (either `WizardAddressController` or `DashboardAddressController`) after the POST is done? Both controllers will need the created address.

Comment: You can pass a method from the controller to handle completion. So your directive markup could be something like `<form-address on-done="ctrl.handleDone()"></form-address>`.

Comment: @Mauro May be you can create a service and keep your contexted data there and use the data from there in your directive. In that case you can have your created data persisted across your different controllers.

Comment: @AdityaSethi, I see a directive more suitable for this use since it allows a template right out of the box!

Comment: @Mauro Yes, I was suggesting service just to pass data within controllers on top of directive

Comment: @AdityaSethi, oh, I'm already using services for my models and there's no additional data that the controllers need to share. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excelent candidate for a directive. Create a custom directive and pass it the callback to call after finish.

You will  share scope with the parent controller so you can update the data.

Comment: Oh, the callback thing answered my question to the comment from @Puigcerber on the question. I'll try it out and be back with the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm struggling with where to put the submit button since it needs to be different for both cases (regular window and modal window) Inside the template and do some CSS magic? Outside and do some jQuery to submit the form from outside? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag