# how to submit form from outside form using button in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to submit a form on `next()` and `saveStep()` using angular

I can't write `next()` and `saveStep()` inside the form

I have written my `ng-click` for `next()` and `saveStep()` at below

when I am submiting the form from inside the form its working fine

this is a code for stripe for generating the token

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content_wrap">
    <div class="content_title centered">Order an SOA</div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_title title_custom">PAYMENT
        <div>Please provide credit card details</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form_element table_wrap">
        <table class="form_element_table center-aligned right-border">
          <thead>
            <th class="no-background">Order Summary</th>
            <th class="no-background">Credit Card Details</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="inner-table-element">
                  <div class="inner-table-cell">Advice - SMSF Establishment</div>
                  <div class="inner-table-cell small">$ {{smf_Fee}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="inner-table-element">
                  <div class="inner-table-cell">Advice - Property in Super</div>
                  <div class="inner-table-cell small">$ {{buy_property_Fee}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="inner-table-element top-border">
                  <div class="inner-table-cell">Total</div>
                  <div class="inner-table-cell small">$ {{totalFee}}</div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <!--<td>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-element front-space">-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell">Card Number</div>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell align-right"><input type="text" ng-model="step6.cardNumber"/></div>-->
              <!--</div>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-element front-space">-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell">CVC</div>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell align-right"><input type="text"  ng-model="step6.cvc"/></div>-->
              <!--</div>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-element front-space">-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell">Expiry (MM/YY)</div>-->
              <!--<div class="inner-table-cell align-right"><input type="text"  ng-model="step6.expiry"/></div>-->
              <!--</div>-->
              <!--</td>-->
              <td>
                <form action="/plan/account/charge" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                  <div class="inner-table-element front-space">
                    <div class="inner-table-cell">Card Number</div>
                    <div class="inner-table-cell align-right">
                      <input class="card_number" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card Number" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner-table-element front-space">
                    <div class="inner-table-cell">CVC</div>
                    <div class="inner-table-cell align-right">
                      <input class="cvc" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner-table-element front-space">
                    <div class="inner-table-cell">Expiry</div>
                    <div class="inner-table-cell align-right">
                      <input class="payment_text exp_month expiry" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" />
                      <span>/</span>
                      <input class="payment_text exp_year expiry" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YYYY" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="form_element nav_btn_wrap">
        <div class="btn back-btn" ng-click="back();">
          <span>Back</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn next-btn" ng-click="saveStep();">
          <span>Save</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn next-btn" ng-click="next();">
          <span>Next</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
accountantApp.controller("step6Controller", function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.buy_property_Fee = $rootScope.soaFormData["step1"].buy_property_Fee;
  $scope.smf_Fee = $rootScope.soaFormData["step1"].smf_Fee;
  $scope.totalFee = $rootScope.soaFormData["step1"].totalFee;
  $scope.step6 = {
    cardNumber: "",
    cvc: "",
    expiry: ""
  }
  $scope.back = function() {
    $scope.onBacKEvent();
  };
  $scope.saveStep = function() {
    var count = 0;
    $(".form_element_table input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css({
          "border": "1px solid red"
        });
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          "border": "1px solid #CDC5C5"
        });
        count++;
      }
    });
    if (count != $(".form_element_table input").length) {
      $.toast({
        heading: 'Error',
        text: 'Please fill the fields',
        showHideTransition: 'fade',
        icon: 'error'
      });
      return;
    }
    $rootScope.soaFormData["step6"] = $scope.step6;
    $rootScope.stepsCompleted.push("step6");

    $rootScope.saveSoa(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
  };
  $scope.next = function() {

    var count = 0;
    $(".form_element_table input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css({
          "border": "1px solid red"
        });
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          "border": "1px solid #CDC5C5"
        });
        count++;
      }
    });
    if (count != $(".form_element_table input").length) {
      $.toast({
        heading: 'Error',
        text: 'Please fill the fields',
        showHideTransition: 'fade',
        icon: 'error'
      });
      return;
    }
    $rootScope.soaFormData["step6"] = $scope.step6;
    $rootScope.stepsCompleted.push("step6");
    $location.path("/step7");
  };
});
```

Comment: If you put ng-model on your inputs it wouldn't matter where you put the submit buttons.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff yes it does matter because an `<input type="submit">` submits whatever form it is nested in.  If you are using `<input type="button" ng-click="doSubmit();">` then you are right it doesn't matter where you put it, but the `doSubmit` function needs to do the work of submitting the `ng-modeled` data.

Answer (score 1):

Reference to [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

NOTE THIS IS NOT MY CODE ITS IS FROM: http://jsfiddle.net/erdt761h/

It looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
     <input type="text" name="q" />
     <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" />
</form>

<label for="submit-form">ProxyButton</label>

</body>
<script>


</script>
</html>
```

Give the credit to the people that wrote this on the other page his/her user is(as of right now) "Kumar". **But the general idea of the code is to still have a submit button hidden by css and is interacted with via a label which you can style it into a button.** On the other page people also talked about just moving the submit button with css to make it look like its outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Core JS DOM form objects have a `submit()` function.

You could try adding to your `next()` and `saveStep()` functions:

```
document.getElementById('payment-form').submit();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13312686)

Comment: @eisbehr I expanded my answer a little bit, and I do feel that it answers the question directly and concisely.