# Why can my form submit button not exist in a separate div element?

Tags: css, html

For some reason, when my button should definitely be in a different div element, it is drawn to the screen in a place that makes no sense. Here is the HTML that makes sense to me:

```
<div class="addclientform">
 <form id="addclientform" class="addclientlocation" action="function/addclientfunction.php" method="post">

   <div class="left_clientadd">
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="company">Company Name</label> <input id="company" maxlength="50" class="addcliententry" type="text" name="company"></p>
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="address">Address</label> <input id="address" maxlength="50" class="addcliententry" type="text" name="address"></p>
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="city">&nbsp</label>
       <input maxlength="25" class="addcliententry" id="city" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
       <input maxlength="2" class="addcliententry" id="state" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State">
       <input maxlength="5" class="addcliententry" id="zip" type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
     </p>
   </div>


   <div class="right_clientadd">
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="pricontactname">Primary Contact</label> <input id="priname" maxlength="30" class="addcliententry" type="text" name="pricontactname" placeholder="Name"></p>
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="pricontactemail">&nbsp</label> <input id="priemail" maxlength="100" class="addcliententry" type="text" name="pricontactemail" placeholder="Email"></p>
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="phone">&nbsp</label> <input id="priphone" maxlength="12" class="addcliententry" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"></p>
     <p class="line_of_client_entry"><label for="active">Active</label><select id="active" class="addcliententry" name="active"> <option value="true">Yes</option> <option value="false">No</option></p>
   </div>
 </form>
 </div>
   <div class="buttonholder">
   <input class="addcliententry" id="addclientbutton" type="submit" value="Add client to database" form="addclientform">
   </div>
```

As you can see, at the bottom, an entirely new div is created where I put the button. But, on the page, things look like this:

[Page with inspect open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2duN.png)

[My code proving that the element is clearly not in that p> tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjP8p.png)

Here is the css for this area, though I don't think its particularly relevant to this question

```
    .line_of_client_entry{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.line_of_client_entry label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.line_of_client_entry input{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}
#city{
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
#state{
  width: 11%;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
#zip{
  width: 14%;
}
#company{
  width: 40%;
}
#priname{
  width: 40%;
}
#priphone{
  width: 20%;
}
#active{
  width: 10%;
}
#addclientbutton{

}
input[type=text].addcliententry {
  width:70%;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
select.addcliententry {
  width:70%;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  margin: 8px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit].addcliententry {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #89b4f9; /* Light Blue */
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type=submit].addcliententry:hover {
  background-color: #4583e8;
}
div.addclientform{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2; /* Light Gray */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
form.addclientlocation{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.left_clientadd, .right_clientadd{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If anyone knows what is going on and can help me fix it, I would love you forever.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)? This isn't valid HTML, unless you only want to support HTML5.

Comment: Missing closing `select` tag.

Comment: The select <select id="active" class="addcliententry" ...> is not closed

Comment: validate your HTML

Comment: @nicholas79171 Thank you a ton, but that's ok. I'm building something just for employees of this company and all use html5 browsers.

Comment: @Teemu Rohit and Giacomo Thank you guys so much, was so lost. Much love

Comment: @JosephThaidigsman Are you saying that was the solution? If so, your problem is solved and we can close this question because it won't have much use for future visitors.