# Netsuite Online Form - Submit button not working

Tags: html, css, forms, netsuite

So I got this form - [Online Form](https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl/compid.822523/.f?formid=77&h=AACffht_hzTbSAY_pN_FbFu_Y3v9R5fcs5A&redirect_count=1&did_javascript_redirect=T) but it's not posting. I've used Suite Answers, Netsuite User Forums and also searching on Stack Overflow to see if my Submit button is wrong but it's not.

I'm using this code -

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Copied from one of the Suite Answers - 'Answer ID 9451'.

I've posted a question on Netsuite User Forums about 3 days ago and not got a reply :(

Secondly - Most of my fields are Mandatory, however, I can't seem to find anything on the Suite Answers to add like a popup error message i.e. Please fill in Title, First Name, Last Name etc.

Can anyone help, please?

Thank you

Comment: It is outside of your `form`. Try putting it inside the `form` tags and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `submit` button falls outside of the `form`

To fix this you could easily move the `submit` button like this

```
<form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
        <!-- Left Column Form Fields -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-6">
        <!-- Right Column Form Fields -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

To further understand why the `submit` button is required in the `form` tags please read this [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag).

It is possible to make this happen with JS but looking at your form it appears their isn't much need for this. I think we also previously discussed in another question that your limited with use of adding `scripts`.

As far as error text, there does appear to be required fields that shoot an error message if missed. If you still have an issue with this, let me know.

Comment: I love you man! Thank you once again. The popup works too - I swear I checked Stack Overflow for this and only found 3 Questions :( I spent days trying to figure this out by myself but couldn't.

Comment: All good, this place is always kind to me after days of ripping my hair out. It is quite often just the simplest of solutions and without fresh eyes, we overthink the issue.

Comment: You too Buddy. If the answer was correct just accept it.