# How to submit a form by clicking on an image in react?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

This is the html inside `return()` of my component. Just a simple form and an image. I want to submit the form by clicking on the image. How could I do it?

```
 <form action="some url" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="first_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="last_name">
    ........
    ........
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

<a
  className="payment-method"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svgIcon}}
/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a hyperlink with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` rather than a submit button with an `<img/>` tag as the content?

Comment: `svg` file does not show without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Ooookay. So there's modules for loading SVG icons, as well as the JS `submit()` function for manually submitting forms via the element's ID. Do either of those work?

Comment: Have you tried using onClick on <a> tag and another option is make sure you have button type 'button' instead of 'submit'. 
For ex. type="button"

Comment: @Jayce444 have not tried any module yet but tried `submit()` function and  it does not work @Krina I tried `onClick` on `<a>` tag by adding `this.refs.form.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"))` on `onClickHandler` function. But does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, input is written as a self-closing tag, so you need to add a forward slash for all inputs; i.e.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

What you need is to wrap your svg inside a submit button, and your svg must be a part of the form. 
Here is a a [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzmKpW)

If you want to do that outside the form, you will mostly need to use [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag). Here is another link, in which I added an onClick handler that invokes the submit button from JS.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GymVvj

Comment: Your second version(outside the form) perfectly working for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help.