# Submit HTML Form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit-button

I am presenting `terms and conditions` modal to the user before registration but I am having an issue submitting the form. I think it might be because the submit button is outside of the form?

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="registerUser" autocomplete="signupForm-noFill" action={{url("/register")}}>
    ...
    <button type="submit" id="registerButton" role="button" class="btn btn-hp-modal btn-signup">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

**Modal (outside the form above)**

```
....
<button type="submit" id="acceptTerms" class="btn btn-hp-modal underline btn-signup-modal">I Accept</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#registerButton').click(function() {
    $("#legalModal").modal("show");
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#acceptTerms").click(function () {
        $("#registerUser").submit();
  });
});
```

What happens when I try to submit the form is refreshing the page and adding a `?` to the end of the url: `/signup?`. If I try submitting it without the modal then it works fine.

Comment: try changing the Modal button to `type="button"`

Comment: Is the modal part of the DOM on document ready?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Comment: Make the accept terms a checkbox inside the form and validate it is checked on submit instead.

Comment: Is the button in modal in another form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is type submit, so it will send data of the form, as the parent `form` tag tells him, and won't considere your `click` function since it change the  page.
You need to prevent the natural behaviour of a submit button.

The way to do this is [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$("#acceptTerms").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent from natural behaviour
    $("#registerUser").submit();
});
```

Comment: OP is returning false which should do basically the same thing