# Submit "forms" using a button outside the <form> tag

Tags: html

How do I go about submitting that form with that submit button outside of the form ?
I used this solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23456905/9263599
But I have three forms, above solution is just used with 1 form and I don't want to use JS.

```
     <form method="get" action="something.php">
         <input type="text" name="name" />
         <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" />
    </form>

     <form method="get" action="something.php">
         <input type="text" name="name" />
         <input type="submit" id="submit-form1" class="hidden" />
    </form>

     <form method="get" action="something.php">
         <input type="text" name="name" />
         <input type="submit" id="submit-form2" class="hidden" />
    </form>

     <button type="submit" name="publish" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
         <label for="submit-form" tabindex="0">Submit</label>
         <label for="submit-form1" tabindex="0"></label>
         <label for="submit-form2" tabindex="0"></label>
     </button>
```

OK. Thank for your answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <form method="get" id="form1" action="something.php">
     <input type="text" name="name" />

</form>

 <form method="get" id="form2" action="something.php">
     <input type="text" name="name" />

</form>

 <form method="get" id="form3" action="something.php">
     <input type="text" name="name" />

</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1">Form1 Submit</button>
<button type="submit" form="form2">Form2 Submit</button>
<button type="submit" form="form3">Form3 Submit</button>

<form method="get" id="form1" action="something.php">
```

Comment: Well, I would ask you if you can find the alternative way to submit Submit "forms" using a button outside the <form> tag since my button which has been created by *ngFor which make the assignment of <button type=submit" form="form1">Form1 Submit</button> impossible.