# ngSubmit not working

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive, angular4-forms

I have an angular 4 form where I am trying to submit data

**HTML Code**

```
<form class="form-horizontal"   [formGroup]="signupForm" 
(ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" >
<fieldset>
  <legend>Scheduler</legend>
    <!--- Gender Block -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="scheduleJob">Schedule Job</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName = "schedulejob"
      id="scheduleJob"
      placeholder="Schedule Job">
```

**Button code**

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>           
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>          

    </div>
```

**Scheduler.TS file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';
/* Import FormControl first */
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scheduler',
  templateUrl: './scheduler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scheduler.component.css']
})
export class SchedulerComponent implements OnInit {

  //Gender list for the select control element
 private scheduleTypeList: string[];
 //Property for the user
 private scheduler:Scheduler;

 private signupForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { } 

  ngOnInit() {   

    this.scheduleTypeList =  ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3'];
    this.signupForm  = this.fb.group({
      schedulejob:  ['', Validators.required] ,               
      frequency: ['', Validators.required],
      days: ['', Validators.required],
      zone: ['', Validators.required],
      schedulerjobtype:['', Validators.required]
  })  
  } 
  public onFormSubmit() {
    this.scheduler = this.signupForm.value;
    if(this.signupForm.valid) {
        this.scheduler = this.signupForm.value;
        console.log(this.scheduler);
      // alert(this.scheduler);
        /* Any API call logic via services goes here */
    }
    //alert(this.scheduler);
    console.log(this.scheduler);
}
}
```

*Why is the execution not passed to onFormSubmit on submit click and alert or console.log not printing values?*

Comment: Is your button inside the form?

Comment: Can you share the `module.ts` which declares  `SchedulerComponent`?

Comment: thanks @chrilewoodz thats the issue, please post as answer i will accept it

Comment: @Chrillewoodz please post it as answer i will accept it

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, if your button is not inside your form it will not submit it.

So change to:

```
<form>
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It is possible however to have it outside if you do it a bit differently, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag).

Comment: That's 30 minutes i am not going to get back - thanks!!

Comment: I had `button type="button"` instead of `button type="submit"`.

Comment: Place the button inside the form as above AND button type must be `submit`.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue because I was not using a `<form>` tag to wrap my form.

Answer (score 3):

you need to put the button code inside the form like below

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  
 [formGroup]="signupForm" 
(ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Scheduler</legend>
<!--- Gender Block -->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="scheduleJob">Schedule Job</label>
<input type="text" formControlName = "schedulejob"
  id="scheduleJob"
  placeholder="Schedule Job">

  <!-- Button Code Here -->

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>           
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>          

  </div>
   <!--  Form ends here -->
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

a small trick you can do is to place an auxiliary hidden button inside the form and let the main button programmatically click the auxiliary button:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit" hidden #btn></button>
</form>
...
<button (click)="btn.click()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The solution in the link of @Chrillewoodz answer is much better. Use the `form` attribute of the button.

Comment: Sure, but beware that the form attribute is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 1):

When it happened to me, I checked literally all the ways possible . Then finally I found the solution is that I did not include the `FormsModule` in `app.module` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the form attribute in the submit button. This attribute uses the form's id to refer to it:

```html
<form id="formID">
      ...
      <button type="submit" form="formID">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was encoutering same issue. After struggling a lot, I realized that I have called `event.stopProgogation()` and `event.preventDefault()` in my button's click method. These method calls was preventing form submission when user clicked the button. Solution of my issue was only removal of these method calls.