# Is my javascript is connected to HTML correctly and triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have my form setup with `id="contactForm"`. When I write `$("#contactForm").submit(function(event){...}` in the corresponding JS file, nothing in it even seems to be triggering.

Whats wrong here?

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  // cancels the form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit hit");
  alert("Submitted");
});
```

```html
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
^ I use this in production, not a CDN 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" action="form-process.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <label for="name"></label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">Name</span> </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-label="First and last name.">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Required</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">Email</span> </div>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" aria-label="Email address." id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Subject</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Music</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Programming</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Just saying hi!</a> </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Subject" id="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend mb-3"> <span class="input-group-text">Message</span> </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" aria-label="Email message."></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="form-submit" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
</div>
<script src="js/email.js"></script>
^ This has the contents of the form logic
```

Here's the link to the [live site](http://noahnethery.com).

Comment: Please include all relevant code here in a [mcve]. External links for code should only be used for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Could you post the code, rather than have us search through your website to try and figure out where its located and where is the issue?

Comment: step 1: verify that what you think you're getting, is what you're getting. Use `console.log` to print what `$("#contactForm")` gives you. Is that actually the form?   If not, you've solved part of your own problem on your own. If it is, that's good information to add to the question, because it means the problem is not with element selection.

Comment: Could be that you are returning false or an the script run into an exception, on the function, which stops the execution of the submit event.

Also, if there are two elements with the same id, the code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your submit button is outside of the `<form>`.
It needs to be within the `<form>` tags in order to submit the form and fire the submit event.

(The button still closes the modal because of `data-dismiss="modal"`.)

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  // cancels the form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit hit");
  alert("Submitted");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" action="form-process.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <label for="name"></label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">Name</span> </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-label="First and last name.">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Required</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">Email</span> </div>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" aria-label="Email address." id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Subject</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Music</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Programming</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Just saying hi!</a> </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Subject" id="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend mb-3"> <span class="input-group-text">Message</span> </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" aria-label="Email message."></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="form-submit" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
</form>
```

If interested, also see [Submit form using a button outside the  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag).

Comment: I made the change to put my button inside <form></form>. It seems submit() is still not working. I am using jquery 3.2.1 and linking the file at the beginning of <body>. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You may want to put your JavaScript just before the end of the `<body>`, use `async`/`defer`, or execute code after the DOM is ready. See [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Comment: I now have it inside <body> at the bottom. The email.js file is still not firing. Chrome JS debugger gives me this error though: `GET blob:http://noahnethery.com/49de1942-e40a-4b67-8898-7954147d3444 0 ()`

Comment: Please create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the problem. The code seems to be working in my example above, but there may be something unknown involved in your code that's causing a problem.

Comment: I've updated it to match closer my HTML document. If I need to post the entire document, I'll do that next if an error can't be found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The button `#form-submit` which submits the form needs to be inside the `<form></form>` block.
Try fixing that and it will work fine.