# submit button in a different component creating Accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, accessibility

I've a react component which renders a form for payment details.
Now, the submit button is being rendered from another component in the same page and it is working as expected.

However, this is resulting into an accessibility issue "This form does not contain a submit button, which creates issues for those who cannot submit the form using the keyboard."

I tried adding an 'id' attribute to the form and 'form' attribute to the button. But it doesn't help.
How could I fix this?

Form:

```
<form id="ccForm">
    <input type="text" className="creditCardNumber" /> 
    ........
    .......
</form>
```

Button:

```
<button for="ccForm">Purchase</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag#answer-23456905

Comment: I checked that already, but it doesn't fix accessibility. It is more about the functionality, which is already working fine in my case.

Comment: _"This form does not contain a submit button, which creates issues for those who cannot submit the form using the keyboard."_ - is that a report from an accessibility checker tool? If so, which one?  Regardless of what the accessibility checker tool says, does the form actually work? Have you tested it with a mouse, keyboard, screen reader?  Does it submit if you press enter while focus is on a form element other than the button?

Comment: Ah, the report comes from HTML_Codesniffer.  I'll give a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach using the `form` attribute to associate a button to a form-owner should work in conforming web browsers.

> I tried adding an 'id' attribute to the form and 'form' attribute to the button. But it doesn't help. How could I fix this?

Aside: you say the form worked *before* you tried this, so I suppose the button has a custom click event listener which triggers form submission?  I'd recommend using the `form` attribute anyway, because the association will set up [implicit submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission), which is a normal expected behaviour.  This is important: don't assume people will use the button itself.

The accessibility error you encountered suggests a deficiency in the accessibility checker tool itself.

> "This form does not contain a submit button, which creates issues for
>   those who cannot submit the form using the keyboard."

I searched for this exact error message, and discovered it comes from the [HTML_Codesniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer) rules (possibly wrapped inside a tool like [pa11y](http://pa11y.org/)).  I looked at the [Javascript code for the test](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/blob/2.2.0/Standards/WCAG2AAA/Sniffs/Principle3/Guideline3_2/3_2_2.js) (in the current version 2.2.0), and it's clearly only looking for submit buttons nested **inside** the `<form>` element itself.

I've filed a bug report with the HTML_Codesniffer project to address this: [Check for submit buttons outside of form element, associated using form attribute](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/issues/226). **Update:** this is now fixed, and will be the next HTML_Codesniffer release.

Meanwhile, you should test the form manually.  Can the form be submitted in all of these ways?

- Pointer click (mouse/finger/stylus touch) on the button.
- By keyboard:

  - When focus is on the button, pressing enter or space should submit the form
  - When focus is on an input inside the form (e.g. text field), pressing enter should submit the form. (This is implicit submission -  the `form` atttribute will facillitate this.)
- Repeat the keyboard tests using a few screen readers.

Comment: A HTML_Codesniffer maintainer responded to my bug report. This check was written before the HTML5  `form` attribute was even a thing. We can expect it to be addressed in a future release.

Comment: I fixed the bug in HTML_Codesniffer myself, and the PR has been merged.  It'll be in the next release, whenever that is.