# Editing feature for react

Tags: reactjs, components, edit

I am implementing edit feature with react now. The problem is that I haven't found the good solution for this yet.
I want to make a view like below.
Both title and description text area are already written with default text.
This text is not placeholder.
If user click the button, User can edit the text.

I tried the below two packages but it is not perfect for my purpose.

[image]

1. TextareaAutosize

   import TextareaAutosize from 'react-autosize-textarea';

TextareaAutosize has a value attribute. but if I use this, I can't edit the text in it. And the defaultValue seems not working.
Do you know how to put a default text value into TextareaAutosize component?

2.AvInput

```
import { AvForm, AvField, AvGroup, AvInput, AvRadioGroup, AvRadio } from 'availity-reactstrap-validation';
```

I think this is another good solution but the submit button seems not to be customized.
I should place the Edit button in the right-upper side of view.
But if I use this package, The submit button is placed at the bottom and it seems like it should be used  tag.

Do you know how to connect my own submit button with AvInput?
The button is in other tags, not in its .

https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/components/avform/

```
 <FormGroup>
    <Button>Submit</Button>
 </FormGroup>
```

3. other solution
   If you have a better solution or experience, plz let me know.

   Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using those packages?

Comment: Just alternate between `p` and `textarea` tags on click. Those packages seem of no help for your purpose.

Comment: @Nagesh Katna  it looks good with react bootstrap components.

Comment: Have you thought of using other than bootstrap such as materialize or semantic UI? They are much better than bootstrap in react and I believe they may solve your problem too.

Comment: Oh thank you.  I will try them. : )

Comment: some one gave a reference like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the below answer and changed UX.

[Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces. This is discussed in the section on intrinsic events. Note that controls outside a form cannot be successful controls.

submit button seems to be included in the form tag.