# How can I call a jQuery function from form submit inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I call a jQuery function from the Submit button?

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <table id="tablefriendsname2" class="table form-table-editadd">
        <tbody>
          <form id="addData" submit="addData"></form>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </div>
```

```js
$('#addData').submit(function(e) {
  alert("asasas");
});
```

Comment: where is the submit button?

Comment: You capture the event exactly as you currently do. Is there an issue? Your `form` is empty so it seems like that's an issue in itself

Comment: iss added submit button

Comment: it's actually outside the form

Comment: set form attribute to the `form` , https://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag

Comment: Note that this is a really bad idea for a whole range of accessibility and HTML syntax reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fire the submit event on the form for it to run the event handler.

Your submit button won't do that because it isn't associated with the form.

Either:

- Put the submit button **inside the form**
- Add a `form` attribute to the table referencing the `id` of the form

---

Aside: You can't have a form as a child element of a tbody element. This will cause you problems. Write [valid HTML](https://validator.nu/).