# React Bootstrap, submit form via React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a React-Bootstrap Form wrapped in functional component, and I wish to *submit* this form and have its `onSubmit` event handled by the component.

However, I can't figure out the combination of `useRef`, `createRef` or `forwardRef` to use to appropriately call the `submit` on the form:

LoginForm.js

```
const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form-custom-margin">
      //...
    </Form>
  )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

MyModal.js

```
const Modal = (props) => {

  // trying to figure out how to establish a ref?

  const handleActionClick(e){
   // want to call LoginForm and "submit" the form and have `onSubmit` method run
  }

  return (
   <Modal>
     <Modal.Body>
      <LoginForm />
     <Modal.Body>
     <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleActionClick}>Login</Button>
     </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to handle it as a ref? wouldn't it be easier to pass the onSubmit as a prop for the LoginForm and in the button that is in the modal footer just put your button as a <Button type="submit"> Login </Button>

Comment: have u tried passing <LoginForm handleActionClick ={handleActionClick} />  and use it in the onSubmit event of the LoginForm  ?

Comment: @jean182 I don't 100% follow - if I set the button as a `submit` button wouldn't I need it to be inside my `<Form></Form>` to trigger the event?

Comment: @nativelectronic how do I trigger the `submit()` event on my form `<Button variant="primary" onClick={handleActionClick}>`?

Comment: Nope, you can have the button outside the form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567605/6064073 . Also react bootstrap allows to use the button component as an input. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#button-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this approach, taking advantage of the form attribute in html5

On the form:

```
import React from "react";

import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function LoginForm({ handleSubmit }) {
  return (
   // Remember to pass an id that will be referenced on the submit button
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="myForm">
      { /* Your Form JSX */}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Now that you have assigned an id for the form and you are accepting a onSubmit function as a prop you can do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import FormExample from "./Form";

export default function ModalExample() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  // Pass this callback to the LoginForm
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form was submitted, now the modal can be closed");
    handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <LoginForm handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
         {/* Here the form attribute is referencing the form with the id myForm which is the LoginForm */}
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" form="myForm">
            Login
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

The most important part here is that we are creating a callback for the onSubmit handler of the form that we will pass a prop. Secondly notice that the modal footer has a button with the **form** attribute, in this case it will reference the form id attribute that you added on the Form component.

Here's a quick sandbox in case you want to see it in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-banzai-oockb

Comment: ! Got it I don't even need the handler - just need to match that `form` attribute on the `Button` to my form and it calls the correct submit method.