# Submitting without the form-tag

Tags: html, forms, post, submit

I am following a course and as a test I have to make a vacation booking page.
The name & address information need to be in between the form tag. After that they want some input labels outside the form tags but the info does need to be submitted with the submit button. I have no idea how to do this.
If you see anything that is incorrect, pleas let me know.

This is what I have:

```
    <form action="https://jkorpela.fi/cgi-bin/echo.cgi." method="post" name="naw">
        <label for="Voornaam">Voornaam:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Voornaam" id="Voornaam" required><p>
        <label for="tussenvoegsels">Tussenvoegsels:</label>
            <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsels" id="tussenvoegsels"><p>
        <label for="achternaam">Achternaam:</label>
            <input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" required><p>
        <label for="adres">Adres:</label>
            <input type="text" name="adres" id="adres" required><p>
        <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
            <input id="postcode" name="postcode" value="9999AB" required><p>
        <label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats:</label>
            <input id="woonplaats" name="woonplaats" required><p>                    
        <label for="Telnummer">Tel-nummer:</label>
            <input type="tel" pattern="0\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{6,8}" minlength="10" maxlength="11" name="Telnummer" required><p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="uwnaam@domein.nl"><p>
    </form>

    <h3>Uw reservering</h3>  
        <label for="personen">Aantal personen:</label>
            <input id="personen"  name="personen" type="number" min="1" max="10"><p>
        <label for="datum">Aankomst:</label>
            <input id="datum" name="aankomst" type="date"><p>

                <label for="typeverblijf">Type verblijf:</label>
                <select id="typeverblijf" name="typeverblijf">
                    <option value="1">Logies</option>
                    <option value="2">Logies met ontbijt</option>
                    <option value="3">Halfpension</option>
                    <option value="4">Volpension</option>
                </select><p>

                <label for="slider">Verblijfsduur:</label><br>
                
                <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="10">Aantal dagen: 
                <span class="waarde"></span>

                <script>
                    const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
                    const waarde = document.querySelector('.waarde');
                    slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
                        waarde.innerHTML = slider.value;
                    });
                    waarde.innerHTML = slider.value;
                    </script><p>


                     Wenst u een annuleringsverzekering af te nemen?<br>
                    <label for="opt1"><input id="opt1" type="radio" name="verzk" Value="ja">Ja</label>
                    <label for="opt2"><input id="opt2" type = "radio" name="verzk" Value="nee">Nee</label><p>
             
                    
                <label for="opmerking">Opmerkingen:</label>
                <textarea id="opmerking" name="opmerking" rows="5" cols="30">
                </textarea><p>

                                    
            <p>Bevestig u boeking met de onderstaande knop.</p>
            <button type="submit" id="sumbit" value="Bevestig">Bevestig</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button is outside of the form, you need to reference the form on the button giving the form an ID.

This should help: [Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)