# How to set the default button in content page using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, button, master-pages, content-pages

I need to set the content page default button. My code is like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
defaultbutton="BtnSearch" defaultfocus="TxtSearchValue">
```

It is working fine, but my master page menu have one image button like chat, I can press the enter key to fire image button click event but it does not fire default button in content page.

How to handle this type of issue?

Comment: You should be able to use the following resource http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/04/421647.aspx to solve this problem

Comment: It's an error focus not the Default button..@bUKaneer

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Master page DefaultButton override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614797/asp-net-master-page-defaultbutton-override)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1) You simply have to do:

```
this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnId.UniqueID;
```

**OR**

2) Using Javascript:

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid)
{

  var evt = e ? e : window.event;

  var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);

  if (bt)
  {
      if (evt.keyCode == 13)
      {
            bt.click();
            return false;
      }
  }
}
```

And from the code behind:

```
ContentPage.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:return 
clickButton(event,'" + btnSearch.ClientID + "');");
```

Comment: this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnId.UniqueID; i wrote this code problem is press enter key it always fire one button , press tab button to focus another button click enter button not working , press space button it working fine , but i have to press enter button

Comment: you can try the second solution for this..It should work..@hmk

Comment: where i can write ContentPage.Attributes.Add , i mean master page code behind or content  page code behind

Comment: In Page_Load event of content load and also the javascript function..@hmk

Comment: i can write the contentpageid.attributes it have shown error Doesnt Exit in content page load event

Comment: use `this.Form` instead of `contentpageid`

Comment: it is also same problem , press enter button always fire btnSearch event ,i can change the focus to another button using tab like another button cancel press enter that time also fire btnsearch event but i have cancel button event please give me suggestion suthar..

Answer (score 11):

I solved a similar problem with the following code.

Thx: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_panel_defaultbutton.asp

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="bt1">

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" />

    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is with Master pages and content panels. This is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

Wrap all the asp.net controls and buttons inside the Panel and set default button property of panel with the id of a button.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.form1.DefaultFocus = txtSearch.ClientID;
        this.Form.DefaultButton = btnSearch.UniqueID;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.ID;
```

Comment: The above should use `btnSave.UniqueID` if there are containers involved (e.g. master pages).