# How do I make my button work by pressing enter?

Tags: asp.net, button, enter

How do I make my button work by pressing enter?

I created a form button and instead of clicking the "log in" button

Is their a way to make the "enter" button on my computer also click to the "log in" button.

---

Code from the comments

```
<form name = "myform"> Password: <input type="password" name="pword"> <input type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick= "validate()"> </p> </form>
```

Comment: what framework are you using, asp.net, winforms or wpf ? Also which language are you using C#, VB.net, .... ?

Comment: <form name = "myform">
Password: <input type="password" name="pword">
<input type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onclick= "validate()">
</p>

</form>

Comment: thats my code above, thank you for helping

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263011/how-to-set-the-default-button-in-content-page-using-asp-net

Answer (score 3):

You tag mentions ASP.NET, if you do use ASP.NET the easiest way is to specify [Default Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) for the form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1" >

    <asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Button"   />            

</form>
```

The example above will specify Button1 as a button that will submit the form when Enter is pressed.

Comment: Thank you, from the code I posted where would I put this code. I tried a few different variations and it dosent seem to work

Comment: @user2773016 so you do not use ASP.NET forms and controls (with attribute `runat="server"`? Just to confirm - you use plain HTML Form/Input elements, *not* ASP.NET ?

Comment: Yes just plain html elements. The button works fine when I click it, but when I press enter it does nothing

Comment: Then you have to use JavaScript solution provided in the link by @EmmadKareem (Here's direct link to answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12263092/961695 use second approach)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your **Login Button** type **"button"**. I would think just by putting a simple input with the type submit would be the best way. Then anytime you push enter within the text inputs it will automatically submit the data.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1" >

   <input type="submit"  value="Log In!" />

</form>
```